# how to set image in item recyclerview when user choose a item in spinner

Tags: java, android, mobile

i have a spinner in add new data, I want the selected data to be an image in the item of recyclerview anyone knows how to make like that

like this but spinner that is from activity not item recycler view and thats the problem, how to get id spinner in adapter

```
holder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                if (item == important){
                    holder.img_category.setImageResource(R.drawable.important);
                }else if (item == notImportant){
                    holder.img_category.setImageResource(R.drawable.notimportant);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: To which extent have you tried? Could you post your code please?

Comment: i tried but forceclose, i tried to call spinner in adapter, and i implement the setOnItemSelectedListener in adapter but cant happen just forceclose,,, and now i need suggestion how to make like that

Comment: Sure share the possible code of whatever you tried so far.

Comment: check again, i add the code

Comment: `==` operator shouldn't be used for string comparison. you can use `equals()` method.

Answer (score 0):

use Glide for image set in imageView check below code.

add -> 'implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0' into your app.gradle

yes check that item getting your desired values using log and use

`if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(important))` to check your if condition.

```
  holder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                    log.e("TAG","Selected ITEM :"+item);
                    if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(important)){
                         Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.important).into(holder.img_category); //here
                    }else if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(notImportant)){
                        Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.notimportant).into(holder.img_category); // here
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: but how to get id spinner,, i get problem on get id spinner from acitvity to adapter

Comment: means your spinner is available in your activity?

Comment: okay! so for that pass your "selectedItem" into constructor of adapter and do process there like this.selectedItem=selectedItem and notifify adapter everytime when you select item of spinner into your activity and check using if condition into your bindviewholder and set image into glide....Understand it or not ?

Comment: i know like that, but idk how to implement thats

Answer (score 0):

Hi look updated answer

```
selectImageType.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
        {
            if(i!=0)
            {
                selectedItem=binding.selectImageType.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Log.e(TAG, "onItemSelected: "+selectedItem);
                if(!selectedItem.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                {
                    spinnerDemoAdapter=new SpinnerDemoAdapter(dataImageList,selectedItem,SpinnerDemoActivity.this);
                    binding.recycleSpinnerDemo.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    binding.recycleSpinnerDemo.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(SpinnerDemoActivity.this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false));
                    binding.recycleSpinnerDemo.setAdapter(spinnerDemoAdapter);
                    spinnerDemoAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

And this below is your adapter code
I take arraylist here and add random values for testing purpose

```
    public SpinnerDemoAdapter(ArrayList<String> arrayList, String selectedItem, Context mContext) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (!selectedItem.equalsIgnoreCase("")) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: "+selectedItem);
            if (selectedItem.equalsIgnoreCase("important")) {
                Glide.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.woman).into(holder.imageview);
            } else if (selectedItem.equalsIgnoreCase("notimportant")) {
                Glide.with(mContext).load(R.drawable.man).into(holder.imageview);
            }
        }

    }
```